# How to read S3 file URL and get it's chunk and then send chunks in socket emit using node js?

Tags: node.js, file, emit

In node, I have to file URL like this.

```
let file = 'https://{{bucketName}}.s3.amazonaws.com/test.mp4'
```

I need to read this file and send the file chunks to all connected user which is work like a live stream.

I tried this,

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {    
  socket.on('stream', function (image) {       
    let  readStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    readStream.on('data',(chunk)=>{
       socket.emit('stream-chunk',chunk);
    });
  });
});
```

I'm unable to get even console of file chunk.

Comment: instead of emit/push on the entire file/stream , could you emit just the mp4's url and then pull the data using normal http/s flow to chunk the content?

Comment: @RobertRowntree Can you please share any example so I can get  more clear idea on it ...